# CentOS w/ IPMI not responding to input?

Tags: linux, ipmi, supermicro, centos6.2

I just installed CentOS Release 6.2 (Final) on one of our machines, however after rebooting post install, the system seems unresponsive to any input. It is sitting at "testsrv login:" but nothing happens when I type.

I have tried both normal keyboard input as well as the virtual keyboard. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you are in video only mode. It shows up in the bar at the top of the window. If there is more then one user using ipmi you might not have control of the session. (you can check in the user list section) You can kick people out of the session by restarting just the ipmi.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem several times with the iKVM Viewer Java webstart application. Here is what I do:

Sometimes rebooting the server creates another user session which may cause the iKVM viewer to enter into the "Video Only" mode. If that happens:

1. Shutdown the server (either through console or from menu in the viewer) and exit the viewer instance. Do not reboot.
2. Launch a fresh viewer instance and check the user list. There should be only one user session.
3. Power on the server from the viewer menu.

If everything goes well you should no longer be in the video only mode.